# Не изменяется позиция маркера в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api

Есть массив, в котором 5 значений долготы и широты, то есть расположение разных объектов. Посмотрел документацию, сделал массив как там. Получилось. Данные отображаются, но вот в интервале, когда в массиве данные обновляются, он не хочет менять позицию. Почему? Речь идет о данных `myLatLng`

Вот кусок кода:

```
//Получаю значения и обновляю.ве ок 
var znak = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html()) || 0,
    lng0 = znak;
var znac = setInterval(function (){
   znak = lng0 = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html());
},2000);
var znak1 = parseFloat($('td').eq(3).html()) || 0,
    lat1 = znak1;
var znac = setInterval(function (){
   znak1 = lat1 = parseFloat($('td').eq(3).html());
},2000);
console.log(znak);
console.log(znak1);
```

//затем кладу его в массив;

```
var myLatLng ={lat:znak,lng:znak1};
  var locations = [
      ['Azer', myLatLng, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];
```

Добавляю на карту и тут все хорошо отображается

```
 var marker, i;
   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
```

//но вот проблема: далее  в интервале массив не хочет изменять свое значение

```
 var setId=setInterval(function (){
   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
  marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]))
  console.log(locations[i][1]);

   }

   }, 2500);
```

Comment: где-то я уже видел такой вопрос :)

Comment: не ну от ты врешь )я уже массив сделал )))прогресирую )))))обидно что грабли одни и те же)

Comment: нужен совет помоги )где что неправьно)Только ненадо мне сново говорить все)

Comment: Всеж вроде правильно ...поставил цикл в таймер поочму не работает ...

Comment: @Grundy where a u?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Проблема заключается в том, что все 4 позиции применяются быстро в цикле. В итоге всегда должна показываться последняя</strike>

А, не, тут все хуже.

1. Создается 4 маркера в первом цикле

   ```
   var marker, i;
   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
   }
   ```

   Но ссылка сохраняется **только** на последний. Из-за этого следует
2. во втором цикле

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
     marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]))
     console.log(locations[i][1]);
   }
   ```

   Ты меняешь позицию *только* последнего маркера, причем она всегда остается той какой и была, так как в итоге маркеру присваивается его исходная координата.
3. Кроме этого, даже если поправить хранение маркеров, при изменении переменных `znak`, и `znak1` **НЕ** изменяется значение в массиве `locations`. То есть у тебя *всегда* постоянные координаты.

Для решения:

1. Сохранять *все* маркеры, например используя массив

   ```
   var markers=[];
   for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
   }
   ```
2. Обновлять позицию только маркеров, которые должны меняться, в данном случае это первый маркер, Без цикла.

   ```
   markers[0].setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]))
   ```

   либо в цикле обновлять все, если все могут меняться, текущий код уже работает для этого случая.
3. чтобы менялись значения в массиве, нужно менять их в объекте, который в этом массиве находится:

   ```
   setInterval(function (){
      myLatLng.lat = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html());
      myLatLng.lng= parseFloat($('td').eq(3).html());
   },2000);
   ```
4. Раз уже интервалы у таймеров одинаковые, нет смысла запускать несколько таймеров, все можно разместить в одном.

Comment: Не вытерпила душа и решили написать ответ?))))спасибо щас прочту о чем он!

Comment: аже если поправить хранение маркеров, при изменении переменных znak, и znak1 НЕ изменяется значение в массиве locations можешь сказать почему это так?

Comment: @elik, так это работает.

Comment: Понятно !спасибо большое щас пробую твои подсказки посматрю что получится)

Comment: Спасибо все четко заработало